# Dude about javascript var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem to take the value into the jquery script , the value must to take it´s route_path_images , but no get show this

```
var route_path_images="http://www.domain.com"

jQuery("#header_background_night_star").fadeIn(2000).css("background-image","url(route_path_images+'/images/icon.png')").show(4000).fadeIn(2500);
```

I think it´s simple buy can´t get works , i don´t know if problem with quotes or what

Thank´s and Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break out of the quotes so that you can concatenate the variable:

```
jQuery("#header_background_night_star")
    .fadeIn(2000)
    .css("background-image","url('" + route_path_images+"/images/icon.png')")
    .show(4000)
    .fadeIn(2500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
jQuery("#header_background_night_star")
      .fadeIn(2000)
      .css("background-image","url('"+route_path_images+"/images/icon.png')")
      .show(4000)
      .fadeIn(2500);
```

You have syntax error at css background image